# DirectX::XMVECTOR function XMVectorSetByIndex() not setting float (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, directx

I am having some trouble performing what seems like it should be a simple task in C++, where I am trying to change the values inside a vector (DirectX::XMVECTOR) using the command XMVectorSetByIndex().

In the code below, the command XMVectorGetByIndex() works fine, with new_y being set to 1.7 (after adding 0.2). However, XMVectorSetByIndex() does not lead to test becoming {0.0f, 1.7f, 2.0f, 0.0f} as I would expect (rather it remains unchanged).

```
    XMVECTOR test = { 0.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 0.0f };
    float new_y = XMVectorGetByIndex(test, 1) + 0.2;
    XMVectorSetByIndex(test, new_y, 1);
```

I've tried a few different things but had no luck getting the function to work. I just can't see what the issue is (especially given XMVectorGetByIndex() works with no issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404810(v=vs.85).aspx (XMVectorSetByIndex)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh404786(v=VS.85).aspx (XMVectorGetByIndex)

Comment: Note that ``XMVectorSetByIndex`` is probably the slowest way to do this operation. If you aren't overly concerned with performance, you should look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know of this wrapper. I assume you mean slow in terms of programming efficiency? Since using the DirectXMath API directly should be faster performance wise (as you suggest).

Comment: The key to SIMD performance is to keep the data in the SIMD registers as much as possible. That means working with ``XMVECTOR`` and ``XMMATRIX`` as local (stack) variables. Anytime you 'spill to memory' it is slower. That said, the usage of SIMD registers is a little restricted particular for per component access so some people find it more difficult to use. The SimpleMath wrapper uses "C++ magic" to make it work like you can access the individual components by converting to and from ``XMVECTOR`` and ``XMMATRIX`` automatically on each operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XMVectorSetByIndex` function returns new vector with modified content, it does not modify input vector inplace. So you should overwrite `test`:

```
test = XMVectorSetByIndex(test, new_y, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

XMVectorSetByIndex does not modify the vector you pass in, it returns the new result instead.

```
XMVECTOR test = { 0.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 0.0f };
float new_y = XMVectorGetByIndex(test, 1) + 0.2;
test = XMVectorSetByIndex(test, new_y, 1);
```